# Rounding half away from zero on entire pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, rounding

I am struggling with trying to get a standard round on a pandas dataframe. I am aware that the round() function doesn't behave as one would expect by design.

Can I please get some help on how to implement the standard rounding that is found in excel. I would like to apply this to an entire pandas dataframe at work in one shot. I believe I am trying to do a "rounding half away from zero" of some sort (sorry for lacking the technical). I am indifferent towards the exact method (would like to avoid loops) but just need a solution that can easily be applied to an entire pandas dataframe.

Here is a simple dataframe. The rounded results should be 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 for each column.

```
data = {
'val1': [i/2 for i in range(1,15,2)],
'val2': [i/2 for i in range(1,15,2)],
'val3': [i/2 for i in range(1,15,2)],
'val4': [i/2 for i in range(1,15,2)]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I've been trying to apply this function to the data frame, which works for a single column, but get an error on the whole dataframe: "TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>"

```
def round_adjusted(n, decimals=0):
    
    def round_half_up(n, decimals=0):
        multiplier = 10 ** decimals
        return math.floor(n*multiplier + 0.5) / multiplier

    rounded_abs = round_half_up(abs(n), decimals)
    return math.copysign(rounded_abs, n)


df['val1'].map(lambda x: round_adjusted(x,0))
```

> Out[62]:
>
> ```
> 0   1.0
> 1   2.0
> 2   3.0
> 3   4.0
> 4   5.0
> 5   6.0
> 6   7.0
> Name: val1, dtype: float64
> ```

Comment: Can you give a simple example of an input number and the desired result? Like 6.54 -> 7.00?

Comment: I would like the "Round half away from zero" (or round half towards infinity): If the fraction of y is exactly 0.5, then q = y + 0.5 if y is positive, and q = y − 0.5 if y is negative. For example, 23.5 gets rounded to 24, and −23.5 gets rounded to −24.

Comment: Are you trying to round numbers to the nearest 0.5?

Comment: Rounding half away from zero. Just like if you round in everyday maths. I do not want the banker's rounding

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the fastest way, probably, but it will work:

```
for col in df.columns:
    df[col] = df[col].map(lambda x: round_adjusted(x, 0))
```

Comment: My apologies - I see that the results work for 1.5 and -1.5 but not for larger values. Doing more research.

Comment: Actually no that is not the case for all, the .round() function doesn't work as expected. Try round(2.5) for example. Further information can be found here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html#tut-fp-issues

Comment: Not a problem. The function I gave above is working, I just can't figure out how to apply it to a whole dataframe -- hitting the error shown above.

Comment: `df['val1'].apply(round_adjusted)` works for me

Comment: Yes, i can apply the above function only for a single column using the .apply() method as well -- however, I can't figure out how to select number of decimals afterwards: df['val1'].apply(round_adjusted), but more importantly I am looking for a solution to apply to the whole dataframe

Comment: This approach also works and allows me to change decimals but still stuck on a single column: df['val1'].map(lambda x: round_adjusted(x,0))

Comment: So this would work:
for col in df.columns:
    df[col] = df[col].map(lambda x: round_adjusted(x, 0))

Comment: Thanks Cerberton, I do realise that the loop would work just wondering if there is a solution outside a loop. I will accept your solution if no other options.